# Storing "CASE WHEN" condition in Doctrine2 entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

As of Doctrine 2.1, the CASE WHEN statement is supported but there isn't a lot of documentation on it. My goal is to set a boolean value to tell if a photo has been favorited by a user:

```
       ->addSelect("CASE WHEN f.photo is NULL THEN false ELSE true END as is_favorited")
       ->leftJoin("p.favorites", 'f', 'WITH', 'f.owner = :viewer')
       ->orderBy("p.date_posted", "DESC")
       ->setParameters(array("owner" => $owner, "viewer" => $viewer));
```

But because my entities are being transformed into json by JMSSerializer, I would like to set the CASE WHEN result as a property on the entity.

```
        ->addSelect("CASE WHEN f.photo is NULL THEN false ELSE true END as p.is_favorited")
```

But unforunately Doctrine does not seem to like this:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 65: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'

Is there an alternative to setting DQL created properties on an entity?

Comment: Does the result set mapping work with DQL?

Comment: Would `->addSelect('f.photo IS NOT NULL')` not have the same effect (but perhaps not trip up Doctrine)?

Comment: Did you try simply encapsulating the `CASE` in `()` like `(CASE WHEN f.photo is NULL THEN false ELSE true END) as is_favorited`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to set property value in query directly. Instead, you can add not-mapped field into entity, and then walk through results and set it. In this case `JMSSerializer` serialize that field and you can set necessary type and other meta information on it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. it will work with DQL

```
->addSelect("SUM(CASE WHEN f.photo is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as p.is_favorited");
```

Comment: I no longer have the setup that initially created this question, but this may be a worth while solution. Does it actually work?

Answer (score -1):

From the error it sounds like it's complaining because you don't have a FROM table listed in your select statement.

Comment: When creating queries directly from a repository you do not need to specify the "from()" as Doctrine will automatically fill that for you. E.g., "$repository->createQueryBuilder('p')"

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add your

```
->from()
```

line that gives the table name for "F" and

Comment: When creating queries directly from a repository you do not need to specify the "from()" as Doctrine will automatically fill that for you.